# Using jquery slider to change filter blur value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jquery slider to change the value of css for a site i am working on. I  would like to add the filter blur effect where users can choose the amount of blur they require for an image, and i am not able to figure out how to append the value to blur(''),following is the code and a [JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanmani/ca7Lrgj2/).

```
$('#slider').slider({
value: 1,
slide: handleSliderChange
});
function handleSliderChange(event, slider){
$('#vardiv').css('filter: blur();',slider.value + 'px');
$("#vardivText").text(slider.value + 'px');   
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [jQuery.css](https://api.jquery.com/css/) call is incorrect. Additionally, jQuery will not automatically vendor prefix the `filter` property (probably because it was originally a non-standard MS property), so you will have to explicitly specify them.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xzuunv19/)

```
$('#slider').slider({
    value: 1,
    slide: handleSliderChange
});

function handleSliderChange(event, slider){
    var blurValue = 'blur(' + slider.value + 'px)';
    $('#vardiv').css({
        '-webkit-filter': blurValue,
           '-moz-filter': blurValue,
            '-ms-filter': blurValue,
             '-o-filter': blurValue,
                'filter': blurValue,
    });

    $("#vardivText").text(slider.value + 'px');   
}
```

Comment: One more question, can it done the same way for border.

Comment: @user3152048 Sure, but you might want to limit it to `border-width` and set the rest by CSS `$('some_element').css('border-width', some_value+'px');`.